# Extra Page showing up When Running my ASP.NET C# facebook app

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, facebook, oauth

I am attempting to get my ASP.NET(C#) facebook app working and it is giving me some problems.

I can get the app to run and auth the user. My problem is that when i run the app outside of the facebook app page(as just a website) my app is running fine, but when i run as an app on facebook(inside the facebook iframe) it shows an extra page. This page is link to my permissions page and if clicked, the app works fine from there.the problem is that the extra page that is showing.

i tried redirecting to the allow permissions page in the Page_init but that did not work. 
i have also tried to to add the javascript(both by hardcoding and adding it dynamically, but that is also not working.

This problem is only when i try to gain permissions from user. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: To "fix" my problem, i abandoned ASP.NET, and made my app in php. good luck to any who has this problem. I am still curious about the solution.